# Core Text Rotation does not properly rotate - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-graphics, core-text

I am attempting to rotate Core Text such that it is readable despite it being generated via a rotated context.

My issue is that regardless of the rotation method, the resulting text is not what is expected.

Here is the working playground:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import XCPlayground


class ClockFace: UIView {

    func drawText(context: CGContextRef, text: NSString, attributes: [String: AnyObject], x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, align: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, 0)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1)
        let font = attributes[NSFontAttributeName] as! UIFont
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text as String, attributes: attributes)

        let textSize = text.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)

        let textPath    = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRect(x: -x, y: y + font.descender, width: ceil(textSize.width), height: ceil(textSize.height)), nil)
        let frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString)
        let frame       = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length), textPath, nil)
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(align * 43.0))
        CTFrameDraw(frame, context)

        return textSize
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let ctx: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        var nums: Int = 0
        for i in 0..<60 {
            CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2)
            CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, CGFloat(6.0 * Double(i) * M_PI / 180))
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                nums++
                drawText(ctx!, text: "\(nums)", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blackColor().CGColor, NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)], x: 42, y: 0, align: CGFloat(6.0 * Double(i) * M_PI / 180))
            }
            CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
        }

    }
}
let myView = ClockFace(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150))
myView.backgroundColor = .lightGrayColor()
XCPShowView("", view: myView)
```

Regardless of the value in CGAffineTransfomMakeRotation the text is illegible.

Why is this? Am I rotating the text correctly?

Regards, Brandon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I draw a clock face based on your codes but revised little bit.

Basically what I did is to flip and move whole clock face outside the for-loop. You can see I moved `CGContextTranslateCTM()` and `CGContextScaleCTM()` from `drawText()` to `drawRect()`. Others are some minor calculation changes owing to above modification.

As to `CGContextSetTextMatrix()`, the rotation happens here is affecting each character but not whole string. You can comment line 19 & 20 and uncomment line 21 to have a different result and see what I mean.

Also if you would like to get the playground file directly, you can download it from [here](https://db.tt/WO6953n6).

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import XCPlayground


class ClockFace: UIView {

    func drawText(context: CGContextRef, text: String, attributes: [String: AnyObject], x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat, align: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        let font = attributes[NSFontAttributeName] as! UIFont
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
        let textSize = text.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)

        let textPath    = CGPathCreateWithRect(CGRect(x: x, y: y + font.descender, width: ceil(textSize.width), height: ceil(textSize.height)), nil)
        let frameSetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attributedString)
        let frame       = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(frameSetter, CFRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length), textPath, nil)

        var transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x + 10, y + font.descender)
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, align)
        //CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(align))
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
        CTFrameDraw(frame, context)

        return textSize
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let ctx: CGContext? = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -45, rect.size.height + 5)
        CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1)
        var nums: Int = 2
        for i in 0..<60 {
            CGContextSaveGState(ctx)
            CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, rect.width / 2, rect.height / 2)
            CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, CGFloat(-6.0 * Double(i) * M_PI / 180))
            if (i % 5 == 0) {
                nums++
                nums = nums > 12 ? nums - 12 : nums
                drawText(ctx!, text: "\(nums)", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)], x: 42, y: 0, align: CGFloat(6.0 * Double(i) * M_PI / 180))

            }
            CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)
        }
    }
}

let view = ClockFace(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150))
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.liveView = view
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Where did you get the values for CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -45, rect.size.height + 5) ?

Comment: @BrandonBradley Actually there is no magic here, it's just a compensation for the geometry x, y position of ``drawText(:text:attributes:x:y:align:)``. The purpose is trying to have a clock face locate at centre.